# Best way to validate an s3 object

Tags: r, validation

As part of some debugging work, I was wondering how to best ensure that an given `S3` object
complies to its class definition?

For example, running `t.test` returns an S3 `htest` object:

```
fit <- t.test(1:4,5:9)
class(fit)
# [1] "htest"
```

The resulting `test` object has certain slots as defined [htest class definition](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/EnvStats/versions/2.3.1/topics/htest.object) as confirmed below:

```
str(fit)
List of 10
 $ statistic  : Named num -4.7
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
 $ parameter  : Named num 6.98
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
 $ p.value    : num 0.00222
 $ conf.int   : num [1:2] -6.77 -2.23
  ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
 $ estimate   : Named num [1:2] 2.5 7
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mean of x" "mean of y"
 $ null.value : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "difference in means"
 $ stderr     : num 0.957
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Welch Two Sample t-test"
 $ data.name  : chr "1:4 and 5:9"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

Now, if I remove part of this object, e.g. `p.value`,

```
fit$p.value <- NULL
```

it wouldn't comply to this class definition anymore.
What is the best way to check for compliance (i.e. the objects is "intact")?
Ideally something like `is.class(fit, "htest")`.

Comment: If this is a concern for you, you shouldn't be using S3 classes. Switch to S4 classes.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no support for validation in S3. You'd need to write something for the specific class from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, it's validating S3 objects from another packages, so can't use S4. I was afraid that I'd have to write something from scratch, are there at least some helper functions or guidlines on how to best do that? Surely someone must have had the same issue.

Comment: If you want to validate the return value of a `*.test` function coming from a contributed package, you're in trouble. There are such functions that do not return a `"htest"` class object. If the function is a base R function, then you're safe, I don't see a reason why someone would assign `NULL` to a `"htest"` list member like in the question. (But that was probably just an example, right?)

Comment: Yes, of course this was only an example to bring the point across. I wouldn't deliberately do this, but to ensure this is not happening by some function that updates S3 objects I was looking for some way to ensure this. My usecase is more complex and I suspect some function to tinker with those objects (that are well defined).

Comment: Unless you KNOW that the other package is causing problems, don't worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a definition for a particular S3 class other than checking the class itself:

```
inherits(fit, "htest")
## [1] TRUE
```

however, if we assume that for a particular class that it is constructed from a named vector with specific names and classes one could check that. This definitely won't work in all cases. I am not even sure that it works for an htest object in all cases and it does not handle the case where the class is a subclass.

```
template <- t.test(1:10, 11:20)

identical(class(template), class(fit)) && 
  identical(Map(class, unclass(template)), Map(class, unclass(fit)))
## [1] TRUE
```

There does exist `stopifnot` in base R and the [validate](https://cran.r-project.org/package=validate) and [erify](https://cran.r-project.org/package=erify) packages on CRAN but you have to define your own validation rules so they would require a certain effort to use.